# Internal Server Error due to long XQuery duration (MarkLogic)

Tags: java, marklogic

I have am currently running through some queries using the Java API provided by MarkLogic. I have installed it through adding the required dependencies to my library. The connection is set up using

```
DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient("localhost", 8000, secContext, ConnectionType.DIRECT);
```

From here some XQueries are ran using the code shown below

```
ServerEvaluationCall evl = client.newServerEval().xquery(query);
EvalResultIterator evr = evl.eval();
while(evr.hasNext()){
//Do something with the results
}
```

However, certain queries takes a long time to process causing an internal error.So Other then reducing the query time required, I am wondering if there is there a way to overcome this? Such as increasing of connection time limit for instance.

====Update===

Query used

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $query-opts := /comments[fn:matches(text,".*generation.*")]

return(
$query-opts, fn:count($query-opts), xdmp:elapsed-time()
)
```

I know the regular expression used can be easily replaced by word-query. But for this instance I would like to just used regular expression for searching.

Example Data

```
<comments>
<date_commented>1998-01-14T04:32:30</date_commented>
<text>iCloud sync settings are not supposed to change after an iOS update. In the case of iOS 10.3 this was due to a bug.</text>
<uri>/comment/000000001415898</uri>
</comments>
```

Comment: Do you have issues with both Select and Update? or Can you explain what kind of queries taking more time?

Comment: It's a very simple query that checks for a certain word using word-query and returns the document, from there I use fn:count() to determine the # of documents. But it is counting millions of documents, which takes up a lot of time. @Ramachandra Reddy

Comment: Instead of `fn:count()` you could use `xdmp:estimate` which does not require loading/parsing the documents into memory and should be alot faster. https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:estimate

Comment: Yes i thought of using that. But the issue is xdmp:estimate counts based on index. So if say I use a path /data[some condition], it will still return me the count of all documents entries with path/data even if the results returned is only 1 document due to the condition applied. @Wagner Michael

Comment: Yea thats true. Can you post your query + data? You could try transforming your data so it does not have multiple nodes per fragments. So path/data is unique per fragment.

Comment: I have updated my post with the query and a sample data. @Wagner Michael.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the basis of your provided data I'd use `xdmp:estimate` and a cts query.

```
xdmp:estimate(cts:search(doc(), cts:and-query((
  cts:directory-query('/comment/'),
  cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("text"), "generation")
))))
```

This will search all documents in your `/comments/` directory for an element `text` containing the word `generation`. As you already know, this will only use indexes and does not require loading/parsing documents.

This also will not find any false-positives because there is only one `text` element per document/fragment (if your shown data is correct).

Comment: One footnote on this good answer:  instead of increasing the timeout (which could start failing again if the size of the database increases), the typical strategy is to page over results in multiple requests.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i would like to ask one final thing. Based on your codes I attempted to replace "cts:element....)" with "/comments[fn:matches(text,".*generation.*")]" and the time taken suddenly increases by a lot. Is there a certain reasoning for this? I tried to run "/comments[fn:matches(text,".*generation.*")]" by itself and it completed in less then a second. @Wagner Michael

Comment: Wildcard searches are the culprit.  Depending on your use case you can look at the options for `lexicon-expand`, `lexicon-expansion-limit` and `limit-check` (https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-word-query) and/or Wild Card indexes (https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/wildcard)

Comment: @WhiteSolstice The XPath expression loads every document fragment containing a `comments` element. In the second filtering stage it then filters out all fragments not containing the word "generation" by regexp. This sucks up alot performance. To better understand this compare both queries using the `xdmp:plan(...)`. I am not sure why the XPath alone is so much faster though. Might be because the query/fragments are already cached.